# Why do I get an error printing from file data but not command line

Tags: python, file, dictionary

So at the Python command line:

```
th = {u'category': u'Hair Color'}
>>> print q
{u'category': u'Hair Color'}
>>> print th['category']
Hair Color
```

Fine this works. But now lets say I have a file named `ant.txt` with the same contents:

```
{u'category': u'Hair Color'}
```

I again want to print both the object and the member just like above.

```
>>> f = open('ant.txt')
>>> q = f.read()
>>> print q
{u'category': u'Hair Color'}
>>> print q['category']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#230>", line 1, in <module>
    print q['category']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I know the reason for the error is I didn't specify an integer.  But why do I get the error here when I've loaded from a file and not when I create at the command line?

What do I need to change to `print q['category']`  when reading from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.read()` reads-in the contents of the file and returns them as a *string* object.  You can see this for yourself by removing `print` and just typing `q`:

```
>>> q
"{u'category': u'Hair Color'}"
>>> print q   # 'print' removes the quotes on each end.
{u'category': u'Hair Color'}
>>>
```

To convert this string representation of a dictionary into an actual dictionary object, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
q = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> import ast
>>> q = "{u'category': u'Hair Color'}"  # Data read from file
>>> type(q)
<class 'str'>
>>> q = ast.literal_eval(q)
>>> q
{'category': 'Hair Color'}
>>> type(q)
<class 'dict'>
>>> q['category']
'Hair Color'
>>>
```